# Unity bugs with external monitor connected to Thinkpad T410 as a second display

Tags: unity, 11.10, multiple-monitors

I have Unity since it came out in ubuntu 11.04. Now upgraded to 11.10 with fresh install and there are few annoying things when using external monitor as a second display to the main on laptop.

1/ Unity top bar is appears on both displays but when clickin on one of the indicators it opens it no problem. On second monitors when clicking on any indicators one click just opens and closes it. Mouse left button needs to be pressed and then indicator menu opens and stays.

2/ When using key conbination super+s, all 4 workspaces are displayed but there are pieces of current wallpaper outside shown workspaces. It certainly looks like completely broken. It was working fine in 11.04, and stopped in Beta 1 Ubuntu 11.10.

Can someone tell me weather those bugs are already reported? Why multi monitor setup is so broken in Unity? Even in current 11.10 release?

Comment: With regards to your first problem, I am experiencing the same bug.

Answer (score 1):

A bug report has already been filed and apparently patched in Oneiric proposed for your first problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/869196